# PrestoSQL parse_datetime with suffix +XX

Tags: sql, presto

In PrestoSQL, I'm trying to use parse_datetime to convert a field to timestamp.
The field is in the format of "2014-01-01 00:00:00+07", I tried using the following but its throwing an error, and I could not find any doc on this format:

```
parse_datetime(row.created_at,'YYYY-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSSSSS+ZZ')
```

Error I'm seeing is
Invalid format: "2014-01-01 00:00:00+00" is malformed at "+00"

What would be the correct way to parse this format of datetime?

Answer (score 0):

You can try `YYYY-MM-dd HH:mm:ssZ` format:

```
trino> select parse_datetime('2014-01-01 00:00:00+00','YYYY-MM-dd HH:mm:ssZ');
            _col0
-----------------------------
 2014-01-01 00:00:00.000 UTC
```